# How can I connect a C# delegate to a boost::signal

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I've try to connect in this way

**TextStore**

```cpp
typedef boost::signals2::signal<VOID(TextStore*, RECT*)> signal_GetCompExt;
signal_GetCompExt       m_sigGetCompExt;
```

**Signal Handler**

```cpp
delegate VOID GetCompsitionExtDelegate(TextStore* textStore, RECT* rect);
VOID onGetCompsitionExt(TextStore* textStore, RECT* rect);
```

**Connect Signal**

```cpp
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
    m_TextStore->m_sigGetCompExt.connect(reinterpret_cast<TextStore::signal_GetCompExt::slot_type*>(Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(gcnew GetCompsitionExtDelegate(this, &AppWrapper::onGetCompsitionExt)).ToPointer()));
```

but it tells me

```
C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

https://github.com/Windmill-City/libtf/blob/master/libtfWrapper/AppWrapper.cpp

**Set Boost Root before build**

Path:`TextServiceFramework\libtf\PropertySheet.props`

**BoostVersion**
boost_1_74_0

Comment: Fonund a post for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304020/how-can-i-boostbind-to-a-member-of-a-managed-class-which-passes-and-returns-a

Comment: sorry for the duplicate question, but i have search for connect delegate to signal, and i got nothing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
typedef void (*GetCompExtCallback)(TextStore* ts, RECT* rect);
m_TextStore->m_sigGetCompExt.connect(reinterpret_cast<GetCompExtCallback>(Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(gcnew GetCompsitionExtDelegate(this, &AppWrapper::onGetCompsitionExt)).ToPointer()));
```